# Using webpack-chain with vue-cli 3 to change the name of the generated file

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

I want to change the name of the generated file from `app.<hash>.js` to `plugin.<hash>.js`. The name of the webpack entry point key is used to determine the name. The vue-cli 3 uses `app` by default as webpack entry point key. So I need to change it. Using `vue inspect > webpack.config.resolved.js` I'm able to see the whole webpack file that gets resolved by vue-cli.

The last part of the resolved webpack file is.

```
  }
  ...
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/main.js'
    ]
  }
```

I can overrule the value by adding with the following to `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // Remove the old entry and add the new one
    config
      .entry('app')
      .clear()
      .add('./plugin/index.js')
  },
  ...
}
```

This is the result in the resolved webpack file.

```
{
  ...
  entry: {
    app: [
      './plugin/index.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

I also want to rename the `app` key to `plugin`. I thought I would be able to delete the key using `config.entry.delete('app')`, but this throws an error.

This is were I am stuck. Anyone have suggestions to delete or rename the entry key?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. You have to use the low-level `config.entryPoints` instead of `config.entry`.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // Remove the old 'app' entry
    config
      .entryPoints
      .delete('app')
    // Add the new 'plugin' entry
    config
      .entry('plugin')
      .add('./plugin/index.js')
    config
      .resolve
      .alias
      .set('@', path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin'))
  },
  ...
}
```

If you want to make this change you have to take the following steps:

1. Rename the `src` directory to `plugin` (optional, but I like it)
2. Add the `vue.config.js` file with the code above including adjusting the alias from `src` to `plugin`
3. Update the `moduleNameMapper` in the `jest.config.js`

   ```
   ...
   moduleNameMapper: {
     '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/plugin/$1'
   },
   ...
   ```

That will do the trick. Now the generated file is called `plugin.<hash>.js`.